# How can I link multiple datasets in the footer of my table in SSRS?

Tags: c#, sql, reporting-services

I'm using SQL Server Reporting Services 2008, with C#, for an ASPX webpage.

Say I have a table of foods.

Then say I group my table by food.
For each food, I need to show quite a bit of information, including:

- list of foods that are similar in taste
- list of possible health risks
- a rating
- etc.

Here was my initial idea on how to do this in SSRS:

1. Start with a data table that gets all the foods
2. Group the table by the food id
3. For each group create a list in the footer that contains fields/tables for all the information for that food (similar foods, health risk, rating, etc.)

My problem:

I thought I'd be able to have datasets for:

- getting all the foods
- getting the similar foods associated with a food id
- getting the health risks associated with a food id
- getting the rating, etc. associated with a food id

Then, in the footer I'd link the food-specific datasets to the food id of that particular group.

BUT, I can't refer to multiple data sets in the footer of a group.

Is there any way to be able to link other data sets in the footer to the food id im grouping my table on?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What specific version of SSRS are you using?

Comment: oh sorry. 2008, ill add that above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can lookup the values on the other datasets based on the current `FoodId`
 for your group:

```
=Lookup(Fields!FoodId.Value, Fields!FoodId.Value, Fields!SimilarFoods.Value, "SimilarFoodsDataset")
```

This assumes a one-to-one relationship between the `FoodId` values. If you have a list of values, say several rows of similar foods for each `FoodId` in the related table, then you want to use subreports or `LookupSet`.

**Subreports**

Subreports are a good option because they work automatically and offer a lot of flexibility for formating and layout. This is certainly the option to use if you are wanting to display multiple fields.

Create a new report called `SimilarFoods`. It should only be a table listing the similar foods and have a parameter called `FoodId`. Its dataset will have SQL like this:

```
SELECT FoodId, SimilarFood
FROM SimilarFoods
WHERE FoodId = @FoodId
```

Back in your main report, in the group footer of your table insert a `Subreport` from the Toolbox and set the `ReportName` to the `SimilarFoods` report you created above (you might want to merge the cells of the footer row so the report takes up the entire length of the table). Right-click on the report and select `Subreport Properties...`, click the `Parameters` tab and add a parameter with `Name` set to `FoodId` and Value set to `[FoodId]` (you can pick this field from the dropdown list).

Now run your report and for each food you will get a list of similar foods in the group footer.

**LookupSet**

[LookupSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240819.aspx) works like `Lookup` but as the name suggests it returns a set of results. The result can't be used directly in a textbox - you have to manipulate it first. However, if you only need one field displayed then it is a good option.

You would use it in an expression like this:

```
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!FoodId.Value, Fields!FoodId.Value, Fields!SimilarFood.Value, "SimilarFoodsDataset"), vbCrLf)
```

Comment: i just found LookupSet. it returns a collection of rows, not just a single value. isn't that what I'm looking for? the only problem is my expression editor (in visual studio) is not recognizing these lookup functions (puts a red squiggly line under 'Lookup').

Comment: Yes, you can use `LookupSet` but the result can't be used directly in a textbox without some manipulation but its reasonably easy to do that. You'll find that subreports might give you more flexibility in layout but I'll add `LookupSet` to the answer.

Comment: yeah, i like the subreport idea best.